# Knn accuracy is 0.0 and SVC accuracy is 0.0

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, knn, svc

I want to train both KNN and SVC on an array of 128d embedding vector for face recognition, but after training, knn and svc accuracy is both 0.0.

The weird thing is that, if I train with a set of about 5 people, the accuray is show 0.6 ~ 0.7, but here I train with a set of about 5000 people, it return 0.0 accuracy.

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import *
from keras.optimizers import *
import tensorflow as tf 
from keras import backend as K 
import h5py 
from keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2 import InceptionResNetV2
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

import time
import pickle


def convnet_model_():
    initial_inceptionv2_model = InceptionResNetV2(weights=None, include_top = False, input_shape = (160, 160, 1))
    x = initial_inceptionv2_model.output
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    x = Dense(4096, activation = 'relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.6)(x)
    x = Dense(4096, activation = 'relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.6)(x)
    x = Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x, axis = 1))(x)
    convnet_model = Model(inputs=initial_inceptionv2_model.input, outputs = x)
    return convnet_model

def deep_rank_model():
    convnet_model = convnet_model_()

    first_input = Input(shape = (160, 160, 1))
    first_conv = Conv2D(96, kernel_size = (8, 8), strides = (16, 16), padding = 'same')(first_input)
    first_max = MaxPool2D(pool_size = (3, 3), strides = (2, 2), padding = 'same')(first_conv)
    first_max = Flatten()(first_max)
    first_max = Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x, axis =1))(first_max)

    second_input = Input(shape = (160, 160, 1))
    second_conv = Conv2D(96, kernel_size = (8, 8), strides = (32, 32), padding = 'same')(second_input)
    second_max = MaxPool2D(pool_size = (7, 7), strides = (4, 4), padding = 'same')(second_conv)
    second_max = Flatten()(second_max)
    second_max = Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x, axis = 1))(second_max)

    merge_one = concatenate([first_max, second_max])
    merge_two = concatenate([merge_one, convnet_model.output])
    emb = Dense(4096)(merge_two)
    emb = Dense(128)(emb)
    l2_norm_final = Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x, axis = 1))(emb)

    final_model = Model(inputs = [first_input, second_input, convnet_model.input], outputs = l2_norm_final)
    return final_model

print("Model: ")
deep_rank_model = deep_rank_model()


from keras.models import load_model
print("Loading pre-trained weight")
deep_rank_model.load_weights("/home/fr/models/model.hdf5")

from tqdm import tqdm

print("Loading data... ")
with open('/home/fr/jsons/X_train_triplet_lfw160.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    X = pickle.load(f)
    X = np.array(X)
    X = np.expand_dims(X, axis=3)
with open('/home/fr/jsons/y_train_triplet_lfw160.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    y = pickle.load(f)
    y = np.array(y)
with open('/home/fr/jsons/name_map_lfw160.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    name_map = pickle.load(f)
with open('/home/fr/jsons/emb128.json', 'r') as f:
    embs128 = json.load(f)
    embs128 = np.array(embs128)

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

print("X: ", np.shape(X))
print("y: ", np.shape(y))
print("name_map: ", np.shape(name_map))
print("embs128: ", np.shape(embs128))

encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(y)

total = np.arange(X.shape[0])
print("Total: ", total)
X = embs128[total]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, shuffle = False) #random_state = 42, shuffle = True)

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1, metric='euclidean')
svc = LinearSVC()

print("Knn training... ")
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
svc.fit(X_train, y_train)
acc_knn = accuracy_score(y_test, knn.predict(X_test))
acc_svc = accuracy_score(y_test, svc.predict(X_test))

print(f'KNN accuracy = {acc_knn}, SVM accuracy = {acc_svc}')
```

Anyone has experienced on this field, can you give me some advise, please? I'm in trouble now.

Comment: I think this is incorrect (positional arguments) `acc_knn = accuracy_score(y_test, knn.predict(X_test))
acc_svc = accuracy_score(y_test, svc.predict(X_test))` Can't you use the .score method with X_test and y_test ?

Comment: why not, I followed this instruction: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/krasserm/face-recognition/blob/master/face-recognition.ipynb?flush_cache=true